# How to (only) remove the surrounding HTML tag(s) from an expression in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, ckeditor

In my content management system, I'm using expressions as `*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*` allow users to generate dynamic content wherever they please. The users modify / create content via CKEditor. Now, the problem is that CKEditor automatically wraps my expressions with a `div` or a `p` or both...

I would like to modify this

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Blablabla</p>
<p>*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*</p> 
<p>Blablabla</p>
```

into this

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Blablabla</p>
*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|* 
<p>Blablabla</p>
```

Could anyone please help me find the way to remove only the surrounding tags (in case nested) of my expressions? Right now I'm using this technique to find and replace my expressions:

```
preg_match_all('/\*\|(.*?)\|\*/', $content, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $mid => $match) {
    $content = str_replace($matches[0][$mid],$match(),$content);    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
preg_replace('#<([a-z0-9]+)>(\*\|.+?\|\*)</\1>#i', '$2', $subject);
```

edit:
Maybe a bit too elaborate and only matches one tag. If p and div are both used, this regex is better:

```
#(<p.*>|<div.*>)+\s*(\*\|.+?\|\*)\s*(</p>|</div>)+#i
```

Comment: +1 But beware that this will only work when the wrapping element is free of attributes

Comment: Updated it to allow attributes and whitespace before and after event expression.

Comment: Different elements than `p` or `div` would also appear, but I think I can make your solution work! Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would one extend your first solution so as to include attributes?

Comment: #<([a-z0-9]+)( .*)?>(\*\|.+?\|\*)</\1>#i because this one is more general than my second regex, I am using ( .*)?. This avoids some corner cases, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having troubles with the implementation... Could you please have a look if I'm doing it right?

`$content = '<h1>*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*</h1>';`
`$content = preg_replace('#<([a-z0-9]+)( .*)?>(*\|.+?\|*)</\1>#i', '$2', $content);`

This gives an error message: compilation failed. Any clues?

Comment: First: Use $3 for replacing. Second: You have some errors in your escaping. Every backslash in the original regex has to be escaped again for the php string. And you did not escape "\*". Original regex is: "#<([a-z0-9]+)( .*)?>(\*\|.+?\|\*)</\1>#i", escaped it is: "#<([a-z0-9]+)( .*)?>(\\\*\\|.+?\\|\\\*)</\\1>#i". I just noticed the the markup engine of stackoverflow removes a backslash, if it is in front of a "*", so I had to escape it one more time. Uh-oh.

Comment: Damn, it seems my problem is still not solved. It appears that CKEditor adds some whitespace (`\r\n`) after the opening tag. Furthermore, I see that if the user plays around with it, stuff like `<p>*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|* *|RECENT_NEWS|*</p>` and `<div>*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*<br />*|RECENT_NEWS|*` is possible. Do you suppose there is a way to work around this? This is much more complex than I thought.

Comment: Also possible would be something like: `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sith ameth<br />*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*</p>`which would have to become `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sith ameth</p>*|UPCOMING_EVENTS|*`

Damn.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried strip_tags? I think this is what you want
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Thanks for answering, but strip_tags() is not what I'm looking for, since it will strip all tags. My goal is to remove only the surrounding tags of the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

if the tags are always identical you can use the `trim()` to strip them from your string.
try it like this.

```
trim($str,'<div><p>');
and
trim($str,'</p></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting... However, the tags are not always identical.

Comment: Seems quite interesting, will try.